# Using JavaScript Onclick Event to pass Data to views.py in Django?

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax, dom-events

I Have a bit of idea about this to use ajax with the JavaScript to send data to views.py but I am not able to do that.

So what I am trying to do is I have put `onclick` event on the image so by clicking on that image I should be able to send some value to views.py.

This is Hello.html file:

```
<img src="" onclick="change()">
```

JavaScript function:

```
function change(){
     // Do something here to send data to views.py
 }
```

Now in views.py

```
def SomeFunction():
    //To get data here
```

Comment: check ajax request to perform any action on server.
checkout this https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp

Comment: This seems too broad. Your have an onclick event; what is stopping you writing some Ajax code in it?

Comment: I am new to ajax so I exactly don't know do. Anyway thank you for reply I will try this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ajax function :

Template:

```
<img src="" onclick="change(foo, bar)">
```

javaScript :

```
function change(foo, bar){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax/foo/',
        data : {
            'foo': foo,
            'bar': bar
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $("#idImg").html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

views.py :

```
def SomeFunction(request):
foo = request.GET.get('foo')
foo = request.GET.get('bar')
...
```

urls.py

```
path('ajax/foo/', views.SomeFunction, name='ajax_foobar'),
```

Comment: Hey Julien, Thank you for the idea.As I am new to ajax is the html page with '/ajax/foo' supposed to exist or is it path to view?

Comment: Hey Akshay, no need to create ajax/foo.html my exemple reload element `$("#idImg").html(data);` after modification with `SomeFunction(request)`. If you don't need reload element `#idImg` you can finish with this :
`success: function (data) {
        
    }`
.
`/ajax/foo` is symbolic link with your view just for run a `SomeFunction(request)` in same page on image and send element with JS.

Comment: Hey ,This url /ajax/foo not able to call the function in views.py(SomeFunction) (I added path in url.py.) This JavaScript code is inside the hello.html file which is already attached to other function in views.py(OtherFunction) & in that function I am able to retrieve the values of bar & foo. But not in the SomeFunction. Any suggestion?